I'm trying to extend Nebular Auth to allow email validation but I'm coming up against errors
I'm building an Angular application using Nebular auth components. I need to add a custom implementation for registering, and also want to include an email validation stage, where the user is entered into the DB as inactive with registration, but is emailed a code in a link which they use to validate their email so they can be marked as active.
I keep getting tied up in dependency injection knots, but I don't see where I'm going wrong. I'd really appreciate some eyes on this. Thanks!
app.module.ts
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        ThemeModule.forRoot(),
        NbToastrModule.forRoot(),
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
            metaReducers,
            runtimeChecks: {
                strictStateImmutability: true,
                strictActionImmutability: true,
            },
        }),
        EffectsModule.forRoot(),
        NbAuthModule.forRoot({
            strategies: [
                CustomAuthStrategy.setup({
                    name: "email",
                    baseEndpoint: "/auth/",
                    login: {
                        endpoint: "login",
                        redirect: {
                            success: HOME_PAGE,
                            failure: null,
                        },
                    },
                    register: {
                        endpoint: "register",
                        redirect: {
                            success: null,
                            failure: null,
                        },
                    },
                    verifyemail: {
                        endpoint: "verify",
                    },
                    logout: {
                        endpoint: "",
                    },
                    requestPass: {
                        endpoint: "requestpass",
                    },
                    resetPass: {
                        endpoint: "resetpass",
                    },
                    token: {
                        class: NbAuthJWTToken,
                        key: "token",
                    },
                }),
            ],
            forms: {},
        }),
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AddTokenHeaderHttpRequestInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        },
        ApiService,
        CustomAuthStrategy,
        { provide: NbAuthService, useClass: CustomAuthService },
        NbTokenService,
        HttpClient,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

custom-auth.service.ts:
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
})
export class CustomAuthService extends NbAuthService {
    strategies: NbAuthStrategy[];

    constructor(
        protected tokenService: NbTokenService,
        private injector: Injector,
    ) {
        // Initialize strategies after injector is available
        super(tokenService, []);
        this.strategies = this.injector.get(NbAuthStrategy, []);
    }

    verifyEmail(
        email: string,
        code: string,
        http: HttpClient,
    ): Observable<NbAuthResult> {
        const endpoint = "/auth/verify";
        return http.post(endpoint, { email, code }).pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
                return new NbAuthResult(
                    res.success,
                    res,
                    res.success ? "/auth/login" : null,
                    res.success ? [] : ["Verification failed."],
                    res.success
                        ? ["Email verified successfully. Please log in."]
                        : [],
                );
            }),
        );
    }
}

custom-auth.strategy.ts:
export interface CustomAuthStrategyOptions
    extends NbPasswordAuthStrategyOptions {
    verifyemail?: {
        endpoint: string;
    };
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
})
export class CustomAuthStrategy extends NbPasswordAuthStrategy {
    constructor(
        protected http: HttpClient,
        protected injector: Injector,
        route: ActivatedRoute,
        options: CustomAuthStrategyOptions,
    ) {
        super(http, route);
    }

    static setup(
        options: CustomAuthStrategyOptions,
    ): [typeof CustomAuthStrategy, CustomAuthStrategyOptions] {
        return [CustomAuthStrategy, options];
    }

    protected handleResponse(res: any): NbAuthResult {
        if (res.success) {
            return new NbAuthResult(
                true,
                res,
                this.getOption("register.redirect.success"),
                [],
                res.message,
            );
        } else {
            return new NbAuthResult(
                false,
                res,
                this.getOption("register.redirect.failure"),
                this.getOption("errors.getter")(res),
                this.getOption("messages.getter")(res),
            );
        }
    }

    register(data?: any): Observable<NbAuthResult> {
        return this.http.post(this.getActionEndpoint("register"), data).pipe(
            map((res) => this.handleResponse(res)),
            catchError((res: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                return of(
                    new NbAuthResult(
                        false,
                        res,
                        this.getOption("register.redirect.failure"),
                        this.getOption("errors.getter")(res),
                    ),
                );
            }),
        );
    }
}

At present, I'm getting an error:
Error: This constructor was not compatible with Dependency Injection.
at Module.ɵɵinvalidFactory (core.mjs:10057:11)
at Object.CustomAuthStrategy_Factory [as factory] (
The other error I seem to be alternating with is:
NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for NB_AUTH_STRATEGIES!
Can you help a fried brain out? Thanks!

In the end I worked this out.

Removed the verifyemail definition from the module setup, and everything bar ApiService and HttpClient from the providers.
Removed CustomAuthStrategyOptions and constructor for CustomAuthStrategy. Changed setup to:

static setup(
    options: NbPasswordAuthStrategyOptions,
): [typeof CustomPasswordAuthStrategy, NbPasswordAuthStrategyOptions] {
    return [CustomPasswordAuthStrategy, options];
}

That was enough to prevent the DI errors.
